# unable to send an email after deployment of website using asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to send an email using asp.net MVC 5 I use the number of repositories for email it's working on local but after deployment, it's not working where I am wrong??
and
Less secure app access is ON of Sender Email Id
web site is : [www.upgradnagpur.com](http://www.upgradnagpur.com) (form on popup)

[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhRfx.png)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Index(ContactViewModel contact)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
       email.SendEmail(contact.Name, contact.Mobile, contact.Email, contact.Course);
        
    return View() ;
}
```

[this Error is after deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aMbK.png)

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SmtpCommandException: 5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu
5.7.14 eI_d36d7bp1NZFngrnFGXwwLoYdTokjB3-G6FBS7FlFcxcaluThbeE-YTpCODNN4GNJ8N
5.7.14 CjZxjJ5E066rJOCuVf3xYy2g-AjXr4kaoQfcSbZY2kJxiVYmLHh6-A4kclD4BtVQ>
5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
5.7.14 Learn more at
5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 jl18-20020a17090775d200b006f3ef214da6sm1862389ejc.12 - gsmtp
Unknown location
AuthenticationException: 534: 5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu
5.7.14 eI_d36d7bp1NZFngrnFGXwwLoYdTokjB3-G6FBS7FlFcxcaluThbeE-YTpCODNN4GNJ8N
5.7.14 CjZxjJ5E066rJOCuVf3xYy2g-AjXr4kaoQfcSbZY2kJxiVYmLHh6-A4kclD4BtVQ>
5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
5.7.14 Learn more at
5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 jl18-20020a17090775d200b006f3ef214da6sm1862389ejc.12 - gsmtp
MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.AuthenticateAsync(Encoding encoding, ICredentials credentials, bool doAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken</h2>
```

[email repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMeYd.png)

```
public void SendEmail(string Name, string Mobile, string Email, string Course)
{
    var email = new MimeMessage();
    email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("hexahexainfo@gmail.com"));
    email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(Email));
    email.Subject = "upGrad";
    email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
    {
        Text = $"<div class=\"msg\"style=\"display: block; width:50%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;font-size:20px;background:#f3f3f3;border-radius:5px;box-shadow:2px 2px #ddd; padding:15px; \">" +
        "<div>" +

        "<img style=\"height:100px; margin-left:20px;\" src=\"https://asset.brandfetch.io/idvsI-ggxm/idtgSNSCEv.png\"/>" +
        "<h3 style=\"color:Black; box-shadow:2px 2px red; text-align:center;\">Student Details</h3>" +
        $"<h6>Name   : {Name}</h6>" +
        $"<h6>Mobile : {Mobile}</h6>" +
        $"<h6>Email  : {Email}</h6>" +
        $"<h6>Course : {Course}</h6>" +
        "</div>"
    };

    // send email
    using var smtp = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();
    smtp.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    smtp.Authenticate("hexahexainfo@gmail.com", "hexahexa@4321");
    smtp.Send(email);
    smtp.Disconnect(true);
    smtp.Dispose();
    email.Dispose();

}
```

[program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WOhH.png)

```
using newupgradnagpur.Repositories;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailService, EmailService>();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: If you are trying to send an email using gmail with user/password authentication,  it wouldn't work.  It requires Google authentication process using oauth2.

Comment: May be find another SMTP server for sending emails.   Your code above should work with a normal SMTP server.

Comment: @TanzeelABaig, please check your code, you are exposing the Gmail address and the password, try to delete them and replace them with `user@gmail.com` and `password`.

Comment: Whether this issue only happens after deployment, and works well on local developer environment? Generally the servers are not present in the same country or city where we live in and hence when you host your website on such server and try to send email from your application you might receive error. Thus to resolve it, you will need to open browser on the server and login into Gmail. This makes Gmail understand that the server and its IP Address belongs to you and it will allow you to send emails through your application.